# Create array of Sides to reuse Slides and reorder them in Reveal.JS

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I'm new in Reveal.js and i couldnt find a function to reuse or re-order the Slides.

I would like to create diffrent array from the slides like short version, long version and etc. here is my code:

```
var url = document.location.href;

if (url.match("?userShort$")) { // ends with
 //reorder the existing presentation     
Reveal.setSlides(1,4, 5.1, 5.2, 8, 2, 4.2);
    } else {
//use default (All slides)
Reveal.setSlides(*);
    }
```

Is there any defind function by the Reveal.js or do you have a solution for this feature?

Thnak you in advance